# Traversing C pointer list: weird printf behaviour

Tags: c, list, pointers, printf, yacc

I declared a linked list implemented in C as follows:

```
struct node_List {
    int i;
    char * name;
    struct node_List* next;
};

typedef struct node_List nodeList;
```

Then I declared the list head globally as:

```
nodeList list;        // head of the list - does not contain relevant data
```

Finally, I have a function `id(char * s)` with a string `s` as th only argument.

```
nodeType id(char *s)
{
    nodeType *p;         // another List type

    if ((p = malloc(sizeof(nodeType))) == NULL) {
        // error: out of memory;
    }
    nodeList * node = &list;

    // printf(" ");

    while (node->next != NULL){
        node = node->next;
        if (strcmp(node->name, s) == 0){
            // printf(" ");
            // assign node to an attribute in p
            return p;
       }
    }
    // error: not found;
}
```

The problem is, when i run this program and call `foo("somestring")` the program executes the `error: not found` part and aborts execution, despite the string `somestring` being in the list.
I tried executing the very same program by inserting some `printf()` for debugging purposes, and it works perfectly, except it prints additional characters along with the output.

This happens each time I add some print lines, e.g. if I uncomment the two `printf()`s which I wrote in the example above (one of them or both, i get the same successful result). It doesn't work though if the printf is called with no arguments or with an empty string `""`.

I can't figure out what's happening, I double-checked the list creation and population functions and I am totally sure they work correctly. I tried changing the `while` break condition, but that didn't work, too. I have observed a similar behaviour on both Linux (with gcc) and Windows (using CodeBlocks editor's integrated compiler)

How could a printf directive affect a program so much?

EDIT: This code is part of a syntax analyzer written in Yacc. The whole code can be found below. It's a long read, and it is not completed, but the code above was tested and used to work as explained.

lexer: http://pastebin.com/1TEzzHie

parser: http://pastebin.com/vwCtMhX4

Comment: It looks like you skip first element of your list. In first step of while you use: node = node->next;

Comment: The behavior is probably also dependent on what you initialize `list` to, and how you construct the rest of the linked list.  You are not showing that

Comment: We can't debug partial code. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: step through with a debugger. Also dont malloc return value untill you find the item

Comment: How did you verify that `"somestring"` was in your list?

Comment: @mko `list.next` is initially NULL, and its value is meant to be ignored: variable `list` is just the head of the list, the actual data start from `list.next`

Comment: Just to clarify - are you saying that: With the posted code the string can not be found but If the two printf are uncommented, the string is found?

Comment: @infixed i have debugged list population and creation methods and they work correctly outside this program. Last element's `next` attribute is always set to NULL. The error is _exactly_ "element not found", since I am working with Yacc and I am throwing that error only in that line.

Comment: @4386427 exactly. I didn't change anything else at all.

Comment: @jxh the string was found by running the program with at least one `printf()` uncommented. The whole compiler works correctly by changing just that.

Comment: @Salvioner - the whole thing sounds very strange. A printf statement should **not** change the program behavior in that way. There must be some bug in another part of your code. It could be interesting if you post a complete example, i.e. all your code including main

Comment: @4386427 this code is part of a Yacc syntax analyzer, that's why i couldn't post a more accurate example. I found it extremely weird this behaviour too, but could not find a reasonable solution to it. I'll try to pastebin and link here the whole lexer and parser code, but it's a long reading, and moreover the program is not complete. The fact is, though, that with different test cases the behaviour is exactly the one explained above, and it is correct...

Comment: I've added links to the full code. the list library header can be found here (since StackOverflow won't let me post more than 2 links in the question):
http://pastebin.com/CURqzu1V

Comment: [MCVE]: Your problem is likely that the linked list is not being built correctly.  Detach it all from yacc; test the linked list in isolation.  There's a moderate chance, for example, that you're not copying the strings so that strings in the list all point to the same space  This does not lead to happiness.  You'll have to do the (modestly hard) work of creating the MCVE.  We cannot debug your code from the fragment in the question — the problem probably isn't in that code but in other code.  Create a function to print the contents of the list.  Call it — at the top of the function you show.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i get your point, but the problem here is that it all works correctly by just editing that comment. It seems impossible to me too, but I've tried for hours with different inputs, also on different machines and the behaviour was exacty the same: adding a `printf("anything")` would make the parser work exactly as it is meant to work, removing all of them would make the `while` loop exit without finding the string. I absolutely didn't change anything else while testing this.

Comment: You've got memory corruption issues, most likely.  Or something seriously astray.  Use a machine that has [Valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org/) on it and run with that.  You've done enough work, it sounds like, to know that it is weird, and that the way you're currently trying to debug it doesn't work.  So, you need to go into a different mode of debugging.  Make the code testable; test it in isolation.  Make sure it is clean with Valgrind in isolation.  Then think about plugging it back into your more complex scenario.  Undefined behaviour includes the option of 'appearing to work, mostly'.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your actual problem, but lines 24 to 32 of your lexer should be replaced with `yylval.sIndex = strdup(yytext);` or `yylval.sIndex = strcpy(malloc(yyleng+1), yytext);` (You could replace `malloc` with a call to a function which throws an error if the allocation fails.) There is no point in handwriting the equivalent of `strlen` and `strcpy`, and anyway calling (or computing) `strlen` is unnecessary because you already have that value in `yyleng`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual error is a wrong type declaration of a variable returned by the function:

```
nodeType* createPoint(char* l){
    nodeList* p;

    if((p=malloc(sizeof(nodeList))) == NULL){
         yyerror("out of memory");
    } else {
        // do stuff with p
    }

    return p;
}
```

The function return value was a `nodeType*` and p was instantiated as `nodeList*`.
The declaration of those two types was pretty simple, that's why the program could work.

the working code can be found [here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/u779svdaeuajgl6/calc.zip).

The strange behaviour with `printf()` was probably caused by the heap space needed for printf's arguments: since this function accepts an arbitrary number of parameters, it saves them in a list. This list is instantiated in the heap, there overwriting the old data left there from the wrong implementation of `createPoint`.

Answer (score 0):

When looking in the provided source code, the algorithm to explore the linked list has two ways to miss node in the while-loop comparison.

**Way 1** - starting only from the second node of the list.

Placing `node = node->next;` before the comparison will force the first comparison to be `&(list)->next` instead of `&(list)`.

> To start from the first node, simply place `node = node->next;` after
>   the comparison.

**Way 2** - never ending to the last node of the list.

Using `(node->next != NULL)` in the while condition will force to exit from the loop before comparing the last node => `node->next = NULL;`.

> To end by the last node, simply change the while condition to `(node != NULL)`.

**Solution:**

```
while (node != NULL){ // end from the last node
    if (strcmp(node->name, s) == 0){
        // printf(" ");
        // assign node to an attribute in p
        return p;
    }
    node = node->next; // explore link after comparison
}
```

Comment: As written in a comment and in its declaration, `list` is an empty head, whose value is meant to be ignored.
By placing `node = node->next;` right after the `while` I obtain the same result you describe. The question here is why a single non-empty printf statement could change the behaviour of the code so much, to which probably @JonathanLeffler answered in the best way so far in the comments above